# Why users want to disable cookies?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, privacy, cookies, session-management

I just started to create a new web application. In the documentation, it is written that I have to prepare for the situation where users have disabled cookies. This is not the first time I have read this condition. Can anyone explain me why users want to disable cookies in their browsers?

Comment: That's because they dont want to compromise their privacy by e.g. rejecting cookies until they are not logged-in.

Comment: Just inform the users that cookies are needed to log in.  People who use plugins like CookieSafe shouldn't mind turning cookies on for the websites they want to use.

Comment: According to which documentation browsers should allow users to disable cookies? is there any "RFC X" article?

Comment: @MischaArefiev And lose all customers in the EU. And stop working on any apple browser. If I don’t want cookies that’s none of your business.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Cookies have, historically, been a source of numerous security and privacy concerns.

For example, tracker cookies can be used to identify which websites you've visited and what activities you've done on them:

1. Site A includes hidden `iframe` that points at a tracker service.
2. Tracker service issues a cookie that identifies you, and logs your visit.
3. Site B includes the same hidden `iframe`.
4. Tracker service recognises your cookie, and logs that visit too.
5. Site A and Site B pay the tracker to get information about what other sites their users visited.

This is just one application. There are other ways to use tracker cookies, some of which allow all sorts of nasty attacks such as identity theft.

Another problem is cookie-stealing, which can be used to hijack insecure (i.e. non-HTTPS) sessions. Using an exploit (e.g. XSS) a page might manage to post another site's cookies back to itself, allowing an attacker to steal your session ID. Turning off cookies prevents this.

Due to these problems, users often disable cookies or block them on certain sites for increased privacy and security.

Comment: Luckily most tracking cookies can be blocked by simply disabling third party cookies.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is your documentation current? People used to say this 8-10 years ago, but I'd be surprised if any sensible/reputable & modern (post 2005ish) publication still suggested you try and handle this scenario.

Comment: Turning off cookies might be good for privacy, but it's probably not more secure. In the cases when your cookies can be stolen to impersonate you, turning off cookies will usually just mean you can't log in.

Comment: If you can login even without cookies, it means that the session-id is stored somewhere else (probably in the URL). So unless the XSS exploit is specialised and only "interested" by cookies, it will copy the URL too.

Answer (score 22):

With cookies, advertisers can track users across different websites and even across IP addresses (e.g. for laptop users who move between IP addresses). This has been going on since forever (literally since the beginning of advertising networks, like Google Adwords), but recently the media has been inciting the public against cookies specifically, blaming them as the root cause for privacy violation. <s>It's gone so far that the EU passed something that is supposed to forbid unnecessary cookies without opt-in.</s> (*Update: this is not true, [that law](https://web.archive.org/web/20121103023959/http://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law.aspx) was not about cookies. I seem to have been the one who was misinformed, not the EU.*) Ironically, the Dutch government's website (here the law came into effect a few months ago) doesn't follow the law either.

These cookies are actually, partially, a cause of privacy intrusion. It makes you easy to track, but there are [plenty other ways](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) to tell one user from another. One might also feel like this kind of targeted advertising is okay as it has some benefits for both sides, but that's another subject and a hot debate.

Without cookies, you can hardly keep a user logged-in. Give the appropriate error when cookies turn out to be disabled ("You may not be able to log in, cookies are disabled in your browser, click here for more info."), and I think it's case closed. Most other websites like Facebook and Twitter also won't work without cookies anyway.

*Update: my opinion apparently changed significantly since writing this more than a decade ago. It recently got an upvote but really isn't worthy of one... I've changed two sentences so that it's at least reasonable, but kept the spirit of the answer. I will not delete the answer but leave it available for posterity because some things (like that laptop users may change IP address) are funny to read in today's world and paint a picture of what the world was like back then. Don't take this answer for being accurate, up-to-date, or my current opinion.*

Comment: "_It makes you easy to track, but there are plenty other ways to tell one user from another._" People who disable cookies to avoid being tracked either do not understand that, or they simply expect that so few people disable (or often delete) cookies that very few websites will bother with the more complicated tracking techniques.

Comment: "_recently the media has been inciting the public against those cookies, blaming them as the root cause for privacy violation_" 10 years ago the same "news" articles existed, only a little bit less dramatic.

Comment: OK, I just read [an article](http://www.lepoint.fr/high-tech-internet/amende-historique-infligee-a-google-pour-espionnage-09-08-2012-1494513_47.php) where cookies are defined as "small spy software".

Answer (score 9):

The most common reason is that they've done it accidentally and have no idea they've done it (see paragraph 4 below).

Second most common reason is privacy (paranoia?). Some people are anti-tracking at any expense. I tend to find they don't really understand what cookies are in this instance. More likely they just think "tracking is bad" and turn them off - without having any idea for instance, what the difference is between session cookies, 1st/3rd party cookies etc.

However more importantly, I do not believe it's realistic to account for the situation where a user has disabled cookies on anything but extremely basic websites. It's not possible to avoid using cookies (or an URL based equivalent) in anything other than a basic website with very little user-interaction other than following links to static content. You can forget about logins and shopping baskets, because to create those, you need at least a session or a cookie (and session tracking requires a cookie, or URL equivalent).

**In 12 years as a website developer, the only people I've ever encountered who have disabled cookies, have it done it accidentally. With NO exceptions**, this is because they've been in the settings screen of Internet Explorer and thought that pushing that security/privacy slider up to "High" has got to be better than "Medium". In all cases, they've put it back down to medium, once I've pointed out what effect it has and how many websites it breaks. Often the user has installed a second browser, believing their original browser is "broken" as no websites work with it. As such I believe it's important to tell users they have cookies disabled (using a suitable detection method) if you have a high traffic site.

You an avoid using cookies by storing a unique ID in the URL (.NET and other frameworks suppport this natively) but I believe this simply moves the problem to the URL - and paranoid users may be put off by a URL which is clearly tracking them. Be sure to ensure that if you come up with a homebrew method of doing the same thing, that any URL IDs are tied to the users IP address. If not, you will create an extremely easy method for session hijacking - as a user simply sending a link, will acquire the session state of the sending user.

The vast majority of major websites which require a login, or have a shopping cart function require cookies to work and I do not think it's sensible to try and work around this. You're probably talking of a tiny fraction of 1% of users who have cookies disabled. Ignore stats produced from automatic systems like WebTrends as these will include things like web-crawlers and bots which do not (and have no need to) support cookies, as this will give you a falsely high reading of the number of users who've disabled cookies. You're certainly talking more like 1 in 5000 rather than 1 in 10 users who've disabled cookies and actually still expect websites to work :)

Comment: "_without having any idea for instance, what the difference is between session cookies, 1st/3rd party cookies_" I am not sure I know what a 3rd party cookie is: is there an agreed on definition?

Comment: @curiousguy: [See here to see what is the effect when 3rd party cookies are disabled](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/76709/8340).

Comment: Err..i would not be so sure that few people disable cookies ,  i myself have been living with cookies disabled for centuries and i bet much more people do the same , thete is a thing called "whitelist" that let you choose explicitly what sites you want to permit cookies to be logged in and if an useless site or etc requires cookies i will avaible how much i want/need to use the site? Not that much ? I'll just close the tab and forget it

Comment: @Freedom - no you haven't. Computers haven't even existed for "centuries".  The vast majority of websites do not even work without cookies these days

Answer (score 6):

> In the documentation, it is written that I have to prepare for the situation where users have disabled cookies.

Being "prepared" is not the same thing as making a fully functional login system that works without HTTP cookies.

Users may turn off HTTP cookies to avoid "being tracked"; in this case, you could think of using another approach for session management, like using a secret URL. Keeping the session ID in the URL has some security and usability merits, but also really *serious security and usability issues*, and **this message is not recommending this approach**. Because *the question was not about the security of keeping the session ID in the URL*, I do not want to discuss this (interesting) issue here.

The issue is not just technical, it is an acceptability issue: if the user voluntarily turn off cookies, you can bet he does not want to be tracked. Trying to *get around* the blocking of cookies (even "for his own good") is *very likely* to upset him.

Instead, you can explain users that only session cookies are needed for session management within your Web application, and that it is possible to automatically erase all cookies when the browser is closed.

Comment: Keeping the session ID in the URL is not a good idea, unless you generate session IDs based on IP address *and* OS *and* browser *and* all other information you can gather, and immediately terminating the session if *any* of those doesn't match.  Otherwise a single shared link (or even a single *visited* link — Referer will have the SID) may compromise the account.

Comment: "_Otherwise a single shared link (or even a single visited link — Referer will have the SID) may compromise the account._" It is the responsibility of the user to not share links pointing to his personal account, and it is the responsibility of the webmaster to avoid any direct external links on such pages; redirects are still possible. Also, if the information has any value, it should be transmitted via HTTPS, and `Referer` is usually suppressed in this case.

Comment: @MischaArefiev Using cookies for session-id is also a "silly" idea. It is all kinds of specific flaws, which are **very difficult** to avoid. OTOH, making a Web page with no external links at all can be easily done.

Answer (score 0):

As to *why* people would disable cookies, *privacy* is in the name. Cookies are regulated under authority such as the ePrivacy Directive ("cookie law").

> Cookies are an important tool that can give businesses a great deal of
> insight into their users’ online activity. -https://gdpr.eu/cookies/

As an aside, The originator of Representational State Transfer (REST) stated that cookies were an "inappropriate extension" to HTTP for failing to "match REST's model of application state". He goes on to illustrate proper solutions to replace cookies.

> The same functionality should have been accomplished via
> anonymous authentication and true client-side state. A state mechanism
> that involves preferences can be more efficiently implemented using
> judicious use of context-setting URI rather than cookies, where
> judicious means one URI per state rather than an unbounded number of
> URI due to the embedding of a user-id. Likewise, the use of cookies to
> identify a user-specific "shopping basket" within a server-side
> database could be more efficiently implemented by defining the
> semantics of shopping items within the hypermedia data formats,
> allowing the user agent to select and store those items within their
> own client-side shopping basket, complete with a URI to be used for
> check-out when the client is ready to purchase. -[Architectural Styles and
> the Design of Network-based Software Architectures, Roy Thomas Fielding](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm)