# What's the advantage in allowing 3rd party cookies?

Tags: cookies

I understand why people want to block 3rd party cookies - I would like to know though what would I be missing out from blocking them?

Why do browsers like Chrome have them on by default? Is it simply so Google can track us? Or would it affect our user experience by having them turned off?

Answer (score 1):

You would be missing out on anything that uses cross-domain requests where authentication is necessary.

For example,

- Facebook likes and comments.
- Twitter widgets.
- Websites that work across multiple domains using AJAX.

This is why they are on by default - as to not restrict functionality. HTML5 [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) would not work with credentialed requests with 3rd party cookies disabled.