# In practice, are 3rd party cookies used in Authentication? If they are blocked, what is the UX?

Tags: authentication, cookies, facebook, same-origin-policy, cors

I'm researching the authentication flow in the case that 3rd party cookies are used to authenticate to a website, and are blocked by policy, proxy, or browser settings.

It's clear that [CORS and various plugins](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/76709/396) would fail in the event these are disabled.

I've seen developers do some "creative" things to workaround this limitation...

**Question**

1. What are the workarounds and threats each workaround exposes?
2. What is the most reliable approach? (how does *.StackExchange do it?)

E.g.

- IFrames + blocked 3rd party cookies
- Using stealth cookies (e.g. Evercookie / ETags / etc)
- Referer headers
- SSL / HTTP only cookies
- A backchannel conversation between the two hosts. (trusted)

Comment: Why on earth would you use 3rd party cookies in authentication? I always have them blocked to help reduce the level of tracking and crappy madvertising.

Comment: @JulianKnight Authentication via an IDP, Security.StackExchange.com, and StackOverflow.com.  Additional example: live.com, outlook.com, onedrive.com.  Google, IBM, and all the big guys do the same

Comment: Urm, I think we have some wires crossed here. Authentication might be provided by a different domain - e.g. MS uses login.microsoft.com - but that isn't reliant on 3rd party cookies. Delegated trust is provided via things like OAuth & JWT.

Comment: @JulianKnight If that is the case, then I'm just looking for documentation and workarounds... Disquss, FB, and many others (outside of advertising) rely on 3rd party cookies.

Comment: Just do some research on OAuth & JWT. All the answers are there. But certainly those services don't "rely" on 3rd party cookies otherwise disabling them would disable large parts of the Internet - which certainly doesn't happen.